# HTML5 advice on drawings and images (canvas, SVG)

Tags: html, image, canvas, svg

I'm looking into creating a website that allows people to create their own designs for a certain product.  This product can have straight lines, curves, squares, and various shapes.  I would not only like these people to be able to free hand draw their own artwork, but also be able to drag and drop (or just click in an area) certain stock images onto the template.  I started this project using HTML/Canvas, and have implemented the drawing of freehand/shapes/lines, but I've read a few places that say I should be using SVG for the images.

Reading that I should use SVG for images made me think that since I'm a novice on HTML and website design in general, that I should possibly be doing this differently.  So I was wondering how some people would implement this.  For a good concept, think of a web site that people can design their own T-Shirts.  You just draw on a square canvas, circles/squares/lines/free hand, but can also stick stock photos on there.  Thanks, and I'm not looking for code, just to know if I should be using a mix of HTML/SVG/Canvas, or something completely different that I don't know about.

to summarize....
svg, or canvas.......or both, or something else completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is how i imagine you want it to work:

1. Your customers select a tshirt size and style.
2. An embedded application within your website allows the users to draw
   a nice design they want or import an image
3. A price is calculated based on the size of the tshirt and the size
   of the print
4. Upon succesful payment, you receive on your backend an image of the
   print, the order details and you feed that image into your T-shirt
   printing thingy, you print it and you post it.

If this is right you should consider this: http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html

You will probably want to remove some unnecessary tools from it and fire it up with different configurations based on what kind of tshirt the customer selected. One example is the t-shirt size. If a customer selects a small t-shirt you fire up a smaller drawing size. The list goes on.

You need to have some good JS skills however to be able to play around with SVG-edit because it is massive but from what i feel it fits perfectly to your purposes.

If you want to see the differences between SVG and Canvas read this: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/svg-or-canvas-choosing-between-the-two/. Its pretty straightforward.

Now why did i suggest using SVG-edit? I don't know if there is any other application implemented using canvas that has so many tools and works so nice as SVG-edit.

It has everything you need, including a '''SAVE as PNG'' function which will serve your purposes in case your t-shirt printer doesn't print SVG images.

Comment: I may have gone a little out of scope in answering this question but i hope it helps.

Comment: Absolutely it helps, thanks for all of the information.  One more question for you though.  This appears to be exactly what I need, but I wasn't sure what the difference in all of the downloads here are: http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/downloads/list  Which one should I get if I need to edit it a lot and change its appearance as well as functionality.  I'm sure most ppl would know the answer to this, but once again, I'm new to html and javaScript.  Thanks.

Comment: you would need to edit svgeditor.js mostly but the webapp is highly complex and needs someone experienced in JS to do the changes for you. I highly doubt that you will be able to use it for your purposes if you are a JS novice but my advice is to give it a try and enjoy the pride, if you can manage it:) Good luck!